# spring boot fail to start

Tags: spring-boot, c3p0

I am porting an old application to spring boot and it fail to start with the following message

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0MessageLogger.connectionProperties(Ljava/util/Properties;)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0MessageLogger, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/simoncigoj/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-c3p0/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-c3p0-4.3.11.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/c3p0/internal/C3P0MessageLogger.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/Users/simoncigoj/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-c3p0/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-c3p0-4.3.11.Final.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0MessageLogger
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.goopti</groupId>
<artifactId>services-boot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>services-boot</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Abelium-GoOpti -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abelium.goopti</groupId>
        <artifactId>goopti-db-model</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and my main spring class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ServicesBootApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServicesBootApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you working around the framework? I would suggest removing the `spring-orm`, `hibernate-entitymanager` and `hibernate-c3p0` dependencies. Add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` instead and let Spring Boot configure Hibernate and the datasource.

Comment: Becouse I am porting a legacy app to Spring boot and there are specifics that need to stay as a major refactoring is unfortunately not an option currently

Comment: Still you shouldn't be doing things like that. I don't say you should do massive refactoring, I only state you should use the proper ways of managing dependencies. (And switching the datasource isn't a massive refactoring imho). You are now fighting multiple battles instead of just trying to get your application running.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try